# Replacement announced

Tags: employment

I’m working my notice period on gardening leave and I finish on 1st September but my employer has already filled my role and very publicly announced my replacement. My resignation didn’t go down well and they’ve been pretty unpleasant about it all. Is that something they can do?

Comment: This depends quite a bit on which country your ex-employer is located in. And yes, an employer can be jaded and unpleasant.

Comment: You already resigned and are serving out garden leave, why wouldn't they be able to replace you?

Comment: They can’t until the position become vacant so announcing it in advance on LinkedIn and in the press feels like a pretty unpleasant move

Comment: Do you seriously think it's unreasonable or unusual for the company to have a replacement organised?

Comment: The _position_ is vacant: you are no longer completing the duties required of the role. That you are still being paid by your employer is neither here nor there.

Comment: @MargoH what do you base that on? Jobs are not musical chairs, you don't need someone to physically get up from one for someone else to also sit down. Why do I get a feeling that you are unhappy that they are not in utter disarray over you quitting?

Comment: " Is that something they can do?" - well, from what you tell us, they *have*, so clearly they *can*. Are you asking if they are *legally allowed to* ? If so, you want [law.se]. If not, please do clarify what you are in fact asking

Comment: To the comments above, I picked my replacement so I would absolutely expect them to hire for the role. I wouldn’t expect them to be able to announce or formally put that person in a position that isn’t vacant. 

As for the surmising about how I feel or what I think, you don’t know anything about me and I don’t know why anyone would assume as much.

Comment: @MargoH: The position IS vacant. You are on garden leave, so no one is doing the work.

Comment: @AakashM Legal questions are perfectly on topic here, if they concern questions that every educated HR department should know.

Comment: Is this a union shop?  If so there are probably rules about posting etc per the union contract.  Otherwise, they can hire  and announce as needed to get the work done.

Comment: "Is that something they can do?" - I might be confused by your question.  Are you asking if they can fill an open position? They absolutely can. Why do you care they annouced your relacement.  You are leaving the company, and after September 1st, what the company does or does not do shouldn't worry you.

Answer (score 8):

Generally, and in the absence of any agreements to the contrary: yes, of course they can. You've quit and are no longer contributing to the company. I'm pretty sure your ex-colleagues will be glad to know someone new is joining to pick up the work you previously did.

Or in other words: **this isn't about you**, stop trying to make it so.

Comment: Just a note, it would be a highly unusual agreement.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, in a union shop there are often very explicit rules about job postings/assignments in the CBA.  OP has not mentioned anything that would point toward a union, so unclear in this case.

Answer (score 5):

I would separate the unpleasantness of how you've been treated, and the fact a replacement has already been hired. You don't describe the unpleasantness, so we can't really comment on it, but you have to decide if it's worth the hassle of raising it when you're already leaving. In most cases, it's probably just worth maintaining the higher ground and moving on with your new role.

On the topic of your replacement, it's not clear why you think there has to be a gap between you stopping working and your replacement starting. That doesn't seem to serve your former employer and it doesn't seem to serve you. I'd just move on and look forward to your new role.

Answer (score 4):

> Is that something they can do?

It is the *only* reasonable thing they can do. Not only *can* they, they *should*.

Imagine for a moment you are the security guard, you unlock the building every morning and lock it down every evening. You quit. They put you on gardening leave. What do you expect? Do you really expect them to cease operations for the next month and send everyone home, because nobody can enter the building until *your* last day?

*Obviously* they would appoint a new guard and *obviously* the new guard should start immediately, taking over your duties.

Why would your job be different from that guard?

Comment: And just taking your example further, it wouldn't be unusual to have both guards working at the same time, with the new guard learning from the old guard about proper process etc. before they depart.

Answer (score 2):

In a perfect world (which almost never happens) your replacement would start work before your last day in the office. This allows you to train them. There will be a decrease in performance after you leave, but nothing gets dropped.

In good world, the replacement starts the day after your last day in the office. They are training while trying to support customers, productivity is down, but customers still receive some service.

The company wants to avoid the third scenario. That is when they haven't identified your replacement, and you are already gone.

In your situation they are someplace between the first two. They have somebody there, and they can still contact you if they have a question.

from one of your comments:

> To the comments above, I picked my replacement so I would absolutely
> expect them to hire for the role. I wouldn’t expect them to be able to
> announce or formally put that person in a position that isn’t vacant.

That is a budget issue. They are paying two people. Some places are ok with that.